# Why can't I subtract these two values?

Tags: python

```
first = ("Enter a 3 digit number: ")
second = ("Enter a 3 digit number: ")
first_letter = first[0]
first_letter2 = second[0]
second_letter = first[1]
second_letter2 = second[1]
third_letter = first[2]
third_letter2 = second[2]
subtracting1 = abs(float(first_letter)) - abs(float(first_letter2))
subtracting2 = abs(float(second_letter) - float(second_letter2))
subtracting3 = abs(float(third_letter) - float(third_letter2))
special_difference = subtracting1 + subtracting2 + subtracting3
print("The special distance between", first,"and", second, "is", special_difference)
```

Hi there,

I am trying to create a program which calculates the difference between the sum of the absolute differences between each of the corresponding three digits in the two numbers. For example if the user enters 123 and 456, then the special distance is calculated by the following:

The absolute difference between the first digit of 123 (1) and the first digit of 456 (4) is 3.
The absolute difference between the second digit of 123 (2) and the second digit of 456 (5) is 3.
The absolute difference between the third digit of 123 (3) and the third digit of 456 (6) is 3.
The special difference is 3 + 3 + 3 = 9.

Idle says that there is something wrong with the subtracting_1 bit. It says it cannot be converted to a float. I have checked through the code and I cannot see anything wrong?

Comment: `first` and `second` is assigned as a `str` that both starts with `'Enter'`. perhaps you forgot to insert `input` before `(..)` to actually get the user input by calling that function.

Comment: Also, your first two lines are missing `input()` call e.g. `input("Enter a 3 digit number: ")`

Comment: You should also check for wrong input with `try` and `except`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the first two lines to

```
first = input("Enter a 3 digit number: ")
second = input("Enter a 3 digit number: ")
```

so that the program actually receives input from the user. Otherwise `first` will be the string "Enter a 3 digit number: " instead of a string of a 3-digit number.

Answer (score 0):

You should change this line:

```
subtracting1 = abs(float(first_letter)) - abs(float(first_letter2))
```

For this line

```
subtracting1 = abs(float(first_letter) - float(first_letter2))
```

That's the only difference I see, also make sure you set the numbers as numbers instead of strings

Answer (score 0):

```
    first = input("Enter a 3 digit number: ")
    second = input("Enter a 3 digit number: ")
    first_letter = first[0]
    first_letter2 = second[0]
    second_letter = first[1]
    second_letter2 = second[1]
    third_letter = first[2]
    third_letter2 = second[2]
    subtracting1 = abs(float(first_letter) - float(first_letter2))
    subtracting2 = abs(float(second_letter) - float(second_letter2))
    subtracting3 = abs(float(third_letter) - float(third_letter2))
    
    special_difference = subtracting1 + subtracting2 + subtracting3
    print("The special distance between", first,"and", second, "is", special_difference)
```